# jQuery attribute selector inside certain div

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-selectors, title

I want to fadeout every element inside .wrapper2 div whichs title isn't title="webdesign".
Ive tried something like this

```
$('.wrapper2:not([title=webdesign])').fadeOut("slow");
```

what am i doing wrong?

Edit//
example html

```
<div class="wrapper2">
             <div class="showImg" title="webdesign">
                  <a href="#"><div class="overlay">
                       <div class="contTxt"><span class="topTxt">Ward WP Theme</span><br><span class="topTxt2">Logotype, Webdesign</span></div>
                  </div></a>
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/300/city" alt="" />
             </div>
             <div class="showImg">
                  <a href="#"><div class="overlay">
                       <div class="contTxt"><span class="topTxt">Ward WP Theme</span><br><span class="topTxt2">Logotype, Webdesign</span></div>
                  </div></a>
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/300/nightlife" alt="" />
             </div>
</div>
```

Edit2//
this worked

```
$( ".wrapper2 > [title!=webdesign]" ).fadeOut("slow")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the child selector `>` to get the children of `.wrapper2` whose title is not webdesign

```
$('.wrapper2 > :not([title=webdesign])').fadeOut("slow");
```

Comment: this was a part of it, inside wrapper2 there are sub divs with the titles e.g. webdesign and these have sub divs and elements aswell. those sub sub divs become hidden aswell, how can i only fadeout the direct subdivs of .wrapper2 and not their content?

Comment: Can you post an example of the html

Comment: If all the divs you want to hide are children of `.wrapper2` i.e. they are all one level below then you can use the children combinator.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.wrapper2:not([title=webdesign])')
```

is a selector that returns a collection of objects. Even if the collection only contains one object.
If you are sure that there is only one object, do this:

```
$('.wrapper2:not([title=webdesign])')[0].fadeOut("slow");
```

Otherwise, use `each()`

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Also, make sure your seector is correct, since it is really complex. You can use

```
console.log($('.wrapper2:not([title=webdesign])'));
```

to make sure it is returning what you need

Comment: Btw, the jquery documentation says this about the :not() selector: The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not() selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".wrapper2 [title!=webdesign]").fadeOut("slow")
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/3u8a88ve/